# Javascript - use class name to specify which variable to assign value to

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to be clever with some efficient Javascript but it's causing me headaches and lots of fruitless searching.

I have a set of inputs in a table, each with a given class:

```
...
<tr>
<td><input name="name" type="text" class="markertitle"/></td>
<td><input name="desc" type="text" class="markerdescription"/></td>
<td><input name="address" type="text" class="markeraddress"/></td>
<td><input name="url" type="text" class="markerurl"/></td>
</tr>
...
```

I want to take the value of those classes, use it to specify a given variable (which already exists), then assign the value of the input (using +=) to that variable.

This is what I've come up with, but no joy:

```
    var markertitle = {};
    var markerdescription = {};
    var markeraddress = {};
    var markerurl = {};
    $('#markermatrixadd input').each(function(){
        var field = $(this).attr('class');
        window[field] += $(this).val() + ',';

    });
```

It's dead simple I'm sure, but I think my brain's a bit fried :(

Comment: Watch out for elements with multiple classes or classes without a matching variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vars don't seem to be global. They must be declared outside any function. Besides that, you cannot add anything to an object (`{}`). Use either strings or arrays:

```
var markertitle = ""
var markerdescription = ""
etc

function() ....

    $('#markermatrixadd input').each(function(){
        var field = $(this).attr('class');
        window[field] += $(this).val() + ',';

    });
```

or

```
var markertitle = []
var markerdescription = []
etc

function() ....

    $('#markermatrixadd input').each(function(){
        var field = $(this).attr('class');
        window[field].push($(this).val())

    });
```

Better yet, get rid of `window` and use one single object to store all the data:

```
var data = {
    markertitle: "",
    markerdescription:  ""
}

function() ....

    $('#markermatrixadd input').each(function(){
        var field = $(this).attr('class');
        data[field] += $(this).val() + ',';

    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your third method. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Not at all! Also, pay attention to the @Stefan's comment above.